# Using LINQ query syntax with custom Maybe monad implementation

Tags: c#, functional-programming, monads

I am trying to write a simple `Maybe` monad in C#. I want to be able to use the LINQ query syntax with it. This is what I have come up with so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 

abstract class Maybe<A> {
  public abstract Maybe<B> SelectMany<B>(Func<A, Maybe<B>> f);
  public abstract Maybe<B> Select<B>(Func<A, B> f);
}

class Just<A> : Maybe<A> {
  private readonly A a;

  public Just(A a) {
    this.a = a;
  }

  override public Maybe<B> SelectMany<B>(Func<A, Maybe<B>> f) {
    return f(a);
  }

  override public Maybe<B> Select<B>(Func<A, B> f) {
    return new Just<B>(f(a));
  }

  override public string ToString() {
    return "Just " + a;
  }
}

class Nothing<A> : Maybe<A> {
  override public Maybe<B> SelectMany<B>(Func<A, Maybe<B>> f) {
    return new Nothing<B>();
  }

  override public Maybe<B> Select<B>(Func<A, B> f) {
    return new Nothing<B>();
  }

  override public string ToString() {
    return "Nothing";
  }
}

static class Program {
  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    Maybe<int> m = new Just<int>(12);
    Maybe<int> n = new Nothing<int>();
    Maybe<int> result = from m0 in m
                        from n0 in n
                        select m0 + n0;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
  }
}
```

And this is the error message:

```
prog.cs(48,25): error CS1501: No overload for method `SelectMany' takes `2' arguments
prog.cs(5,28): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Can anyone please guide me on what I should do to be able to use query syntax with my `Maybe` implementation? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SelectMany <strike>must</strike> should be declared as an extension in a static class, for example:

```
public static class Maybe {

   public static Maybe<B> SelectMany<B>(this Maybe<A> maybe, Func<A, Maybe<B>> f) {
       return f(a);
   }

   ...
}
```

**EDIT**:

you still need a piece. With this should work:

```
public static Maybe<V> SelectMany<T, U, V>(this Maybe<T> m, Func<T, Maybe<U>> k, Func<T, U, V> s)
{
  return m.SelectMany(x => k(x).SelectMany(y => new Just<V>(s(x, y))));
}
```

You need this because:

```
 from m0 in m
 from n0 in n
 select m0 + n0
```

would be translated in:

```
 m.SelectMany(m0 => n, (m, n0) => m0 + n0);
```

Instead, for example:

```
 var aa = new List<List<string>>();
 var bb = from a in aa
          from b in a
          select b;
```

is translated in

```
 aa.SelectMany(a => a);
```

Comment: As I understand it, query syntax is sort of a language level macro for regular function calls. Look at this code: http://ideone.com/567NA. I haven't used an extension method, but it works.

Comment: Though I understand why one would in general want to declare these methods as extension methods - that lets you have different return types for the overloads of the same method, which is not possible if we have them as object methods instead.

Comment: I see. Didn't know I could use Linq syntax on regular methods.  Weird! I answered and now i'm thanking you :)

Comment: The code works now. Now I am curious why I have to declare this extra `SelectMany` method with a higher adicity. Can you please explain?

Comment: Updated. The SelectMany with only one param is used when the from forms are chained

Comment: Coming from Scala, C#'s translation rules seem a bit weird. In Scala, the bind operator is called `flatMap`, and it doesn't require the triadic overload that `SelectMany` does. Anyway, thanks so much for the answer. Learnt a couple of new things today. :)

Comment: I'm going to Scala:) and I agree that Scala is very much clearer, as fair as I learnt so far. I wish C# have traits, stackable modifications, variance annotations...